# Seleniums Drag & Drop doesn't work with AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Selenium WebDirver isn't able to drag'n'drop an element on [that AngularJS UI](https://a5hik.github.io/ng-sortable/#/).

After you execute following C#-Code and hover with the mouse pointer over the Webpage, you can see, that it successfully dragged the element, but didn't drop it:

```
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://a5hik.github.io/ng-sortable/#/");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        IWebElement sourceBox = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("(.//span[@class='card-title'])[1]")));
        IWebElement targetBox = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("(.//span[@class='card-title'])[2]")));

        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.DragAndDrop(sourceBox, targetBox).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Selenium doesn't support HTML5 drag and drops yet,  I suspect this is your problem rather than angular.

Comment: Hi Ardesco, thx, that may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try using the below and let me know if still face the issue?

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
.moveToElement(otherElement)
.release(otherElement)
.build();

dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: thx for helping me. Unfortunately it doesn't work neither. I think the problem is deeper: it's about the driver itself. In C# your proposed code is:             `Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            var dragAndDrop = builder.ClickAndHold(sourceBox).MoveToElement(targetBox).Release(targetBox).Build();
            dragAndDrop.Perform(); `

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as solution had to create a class with the custom javascript that does this, it is a bug selenium.
Solution:

Create a file DragAndDrop.js and paste this code:

```
(function() {

var Component = function( element ) {
  element = document.querySelector( element );

  return {
    simulate: simulateFn
  };

  //-------------//

  function simulateFn( elem ) {
    elem = document.querySelector( elem );

    /*Simulating drag start*/
    var type = 'dragstart';
    var event = createEvent( type );
    dispatchEvent( element, type, event );

    /*Simulating drop*/
    type = 'drop';
    var dropEvent = createEvent(type, {});
    dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
    dispatchEvent( elem, type, dropEvent );

    /*Simulating drag end*/
    type = 'dragend';
    var dragEndEvent = createEvent(type, {});
    dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
    dispatchEvent( elem, type, dragEndEvent );
  }

  //------------------//

  function createEvent(type) {

    var event = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
    event.initCustomEvent( type, true, true, null );

    event.dataTransfer = {
      data: {},
      setData: function(type, val){
        this.data[type] = val;
      },
      getData: function(type){
        return this.data[type];
      }
    };
    return event;
  }

  function dispatchEvent(elem, type, event) {
    if(elem.dispatchEvent) {
      elem.dispatchEvent(event);
    }else if( elem.fireEvent ) {
      elem.fireEvent("on"+type, event);
    }
  }

};

window.Drag = Component;
})();
```

And this code for execute action Drag And Drop:

```
String fileContents = Files.toString( new File( "src/test/resources/js/dragAndDrop.js" ), Charsets.UTF_8 );
JavascriptExecutor js = ( JavascriptExecutor ) driver;
js.executeScript( fileContents + "Drag('#column-1').simulate('drop-container');" );
```

Answer (score 0):

To simulate an HTML5 drag and drop:

```
static final String JS_DRAG_AND_DROP =
  "var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEff" +
  "ect:'',effectAllowed:'all',files:[],items:{},types:[],setData:f" +
  "unction(format,data){this.items[format]=data;this.types.append(" +
  "format);},getData:function(format){return this.items[format];}," +
  "clearData:function(format){}};var emit=function(event,target){v" +
  "ar evt=document.createEvent('Event');evt.initEvent(event,true,f" +
  "alse);evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;target.dispatchEvent(evt);}" +
  ";emit('dragstart',src);emit('dragenter',tgt);emit('dragover',tg" +
  "t);emit('drop',tgt);emit('dragend',src);";


WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop");

WebElement ele_drag = driver.findElement(By.id("column-a"));
WebElement ele_drop = driver.findElement(By.id("column-b"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript(JS_DRAG_AND_DROP, new Object[]{ele_drag, ele_drop});
```